# Emulator does not launch

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am following this tutorial first time ever working with android:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

I created a new project, made no changes except to drop a webView in the middle of the main view.

Then I clicked run app and selected the default profile, which was a nexus 5.
The console showed that the app built in 2 seconds.

Then... nothing, no app, no emulator popped up,

The two tabs, "app" and "nexus" show:

app:

```
Waiting for device.
~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

nexus:

```
emulator: device fd:772
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

There is nothing on the UI that indicates that anything is happening at all.
In windows task manager, it shows emulator.exe with 0% cpu and 2gb memory.

I have checked other posts, and I definitely do have the Intel HAXM installed

Where can I even begin troubleshooting what went wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default emulator is very slow, and it may start for a long time. Many developers are using alternative emulators. The best one, is [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It's free, and really fast. If you want know more, read about it [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/product), and how to install it [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download).

[image]

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kHVWwHRFm8) a video instruction, how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing memory size and try other system images

most of the time intel x86 atom system image works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HAXM driver is the latest.

Check to see if there are any updates in the SDK Manager.

The emulator can't load HAX

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) emulator.
It's simple to install and use.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Haxm have many problems . You should try to use https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Its a free, limitated and fast emulator, work with Haxm, and have plugin for Android Studio, and many predefined devices for working with that.